# Why does ExpandAll not work within a symbolic sum?

Tags: symbolic, summation

If I evaluate `Sum[(x + Subscript[y, n])^2, n] + (y + z)^2 // ExpandAll` then the expression within the `Sum` is not expanded, yet if it is replaced with another function such as `Sin` the inner expression is expanded.  Why is this the case and how do I get the desired behaviour?

Answer (score 1):

[`Inactivate`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Inactivate.html) might be helpful here:

```
exp = Inactivate[Sum[(x + y[n])^2, n] + (y + z)^2, Sum];

Activate[ExpandAll[exp]]
(*y^2 + 2*y*z + z^2 + Sum[x^2 + 2*x*y[n] + y[n]^2, n]*)
```

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't work because `Sum` has the attribute `HoldAll`.  You can see this effect with a made-up function,

```
ClearAll@fg
(fg[(x + y[n])^2, n] + (y + z)^2) // ExpandAll
SetAttributes[fg, HoldAll];
(fg[(x + y[n])^2, n] + (y + z)^2) // ExpandAll
(* y^2 + 2 y z + z^2 + fg[x^2 + 2 x y[n] + y[n]^2, n] *)
(* y^2 + 2 y z + z^2 + fg[(x + y[n])^2, n] *)
```

(I replaced your `Subscript[y,n]` with `y[n]` because subscripts are bad mmkay) Before `fg` had the attribute, `ExpandAll` worked just as hoped, but with the attribute you can not expand within `fg`.  I don't see a way to remove this attribute, nor an easy workaround.  Here is something that works though,

```
ClearAll@f;
(Sum[(x + y[n])^2, n] + (y + z)^2) // # /. Sum -> f & // 
  ExpandAll // # /. f -> Sum &
(* y^2 + 2*y*z + z^2 + Sum[x^2 + 2*x*y[n] + y[n]^2, n] *)
```

Comment: If one must: `MapAt[ExpandAll, Sum[(x + y[n])^2, n], 1]`.

Comment: But `MapAt[ExpandAll, Sum[(x + y[n])^2, n] + (y + z)^2, {1}]` doesn't do the trick, you have to resort to mapping `MapAt`, `MapAt[ExpandAll, #, 1] & /@ (Sum[(x + y[n])^2, n] + (y + z)^2)`

Comment: Yes, it was intended as a special treatment for `Sum[]` objects.